# How can I create a log file that stays with an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, carrierwave

I have an `Upload` AR model that can be processed by one of many background jobs, depending on the `file_type` of the upload. To track what happens with each `Upload`, it has a *CarrierWave* field defined on it called `log`.

I want to log the processing of the uploaded file, and save it with the `upload` object in the database. These are large CSV files, and I am not failing a whole file when there is just a problem with one of the records.

I don't know how to write to this `log` from whatever background job that is doing the processing. If I do this:

```
  def logger
    logfile = File.open(self.log_file_name, 'w')  #create log file
    logfile.sync = true  #automatically flushes data to file
    Logger.new(logfile, 10, 500000)
  end
```

on the model, then it's going to instantiate that logfile every time. If I do this:

```
  def logger
    @@logger ||= {}
    @@logger[id] ||= Logger.new(File.open(self.log_file_name, 'w'), 10, 500000)  #create log file
  end
```

That's super-ugly, and I don't know how to set `logfile.sync = true` if I do it that way.

And then I have to have an ugly method to close the file and assign `@@logger` to the `upload.log` field prior to saving.

I've just looked at it too long and can't unsee the ugliness, I'm convinced there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of this gems to simplify your task
https://github.com/shadabahmed/logstasher
https://github.com/roidrage/lograge